# Work with dynamic elements from a custom adapter

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter

Hellow this is my first question in stack.
Im creating a dynamic grid of this tutorial 
http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/09/android-creating-a-custom-adapter-for-gridview-buttonadapter/comment-page-1/

Now it's working pretty good. My layout is composed by a gridView and under this gridView i have a TextView.

The problem is that i want to change the TextView to display different information on each id when the focus changes (on the grid elements). I've tried to use OnFocusChangeListener inside ButtonAdapter, but when trying to get a reference to the textView, it says that findViewById is not implemented.

I wonder how to make a reference in my main activity that allows me to handle my dynamic grid elements.
I have the following in onCreate();

```
    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ButtonAdapter(this));
```

So i want to handle my grid elements from here, any ideas?
Thanks

Edit:
I've been trying to change different things, but im receiving a NullPointerException from my getView method. I can't find a way to make it work, i'll apreciate any help guys, this is my code:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Button btn;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        btn = new Button(mContext);
        btn.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 55));
        btn.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        btn = (Button) convertView;
    }

    btn.setText(filenames[position]);
    // filenames is an array of strings
    btn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    btn.setId(position);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            TextView vt = (TextView) btn.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            vt.setText("Button Pressed");
        }
    });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the right track, but I think it would make most sense to take care of it in your adapter. So findViewById() isn't working for you, but it will work if you change it to convertView.findViewById() (or whatever view is returned in your getView method of your Adapter). From there you will be able to manipulate the TextView.

Comment: Thank you @icecreamman, now i have a nullpointer exception, please give a look at my getView method above.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I am glad that I helped. Can you mark my response as the answer (with the green checkmark)? Thanks! Also, what element is null? The btn or the TextView, or something else?

Comment: Thanks again. The problem is that btn is receiving a NullPointerException, if you look the code above you'll se that there is an OnClickListener and inside it there is the value returned by getView() this is btn. So when i use btn to get a reference of my textView it causes the error.

I just want to know how to refer individual elements of the gridView, for example if i want to make something happens when the user clicks button 1, or button 2. What should i do? I hope you can point me in the right direction
Thank you again!!!

Comment: Assuming each button is an element of the GridView, you will need to use an on OnItemClickListener as opposed to an onClickListener. In fact, there is a pretty nice tutorial as part of the Android Developer Resource that follows this pattern. I highly recommend all of the other tutorials that Google puts out. Here is the link: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

Comment: thank you very much now i have it working properly. You're right, there are pretty good tut's from google.
Really appreciate you're help, thanks again.